# ggplot not saving with the correct font

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to save a plot that uses Arial Narrow. However, it is being displayed correctly in RStudio viewer but the final PNG file uses Sans and not Arial Narrow.

This is a kinda MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(showtext)

# MAIN is a server
font_paths("//MAIN/Fonts")
showtext_auto()
font_add("Arial Narrow", "//MAIN/Fonts/ArialNarrow.ttf")

plot <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
  ggtitle("My tiny example") +
  theme_bw(base_family = "Arial Narrow")

ggsave("myplot.png",
       plot = plot,
       device = png,
       height = 7,
       width = 5,
       units = "cm",
       type = "cairo",
       dpi = 300
      )
```

I also used this

```
png(file = "myplot.png",
    width = 7,
    height = 5,
    unit = "cm",
    family = "Arial Narrow",
    res = 300
   )
 plot(plot)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Try save it with `png()`

Comment: yes, I did that (I had a typo in my original post, I just wrote 'png' in the second block, I was thinking about other format when I wrote the MWE)